# Why STOMP protocol has ACK and NACK, if delivery of frames already guaranteed by TCP?

Tags: stomp

STOMP seems to be a protocol for socket based communication, and AFAIK socket always means TCP.

Why does STOMP needs ACK/NACK commands for acknowledging messages, if it's already guaranteed that the messages will be delivered on protocol level?

https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#ACK

Comment: "socket always means TCP" - [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket#Types), but some of the assumptions of STOMP require a *reliable* streaming protocol below it, *such as* TCP. So your question is "still valid" but badly framed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the STOMP ACK/NACK functionality doesn't really have anything to do with the transport protocol (i.e. tcp). It's really about the messaging client and how it interacts with the message from the broker. For example, a client could receive a message, process it, and if the processing result was "successful" then it would ACK the message. If the processing result was a "failure" then it would NACK the message. As [the spec](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#NACK) states, when a message is NACKed:

> The server can then either send the message to a different client, discard it, or put it in a dead letter queue.

This allows messaging applications to deal with potentially bad messages as well as malfunctioning clients.

There are other use-cases, but this is probably the most common and straight-forward.

Comment: so it's just application level error? makes sense. sounds inflexible though, no way to specify error code or error message.

Comment: I wouldn't call the ACK/NACK functionality an application level error. It's a feature of the messaging protocol which applications can use to potentially deal with message processing errors. As far as specifying an error code/message, this is par for the course with messaging protocols. I'm not aware of any messaging protocol which allows a client to NACK a message with some kind of error code/message.

Comment: How would the server decide what to do with a NACKed message? Would the server ignore the message? Would the server resend the message? Would the server put the message in 'failed' queue? 
Is it something which is message specific (server chooses what to do based on message type), or does the server need to have a blanket rule for that behaviour?

Comment: The STOMP specification doesn't dictate specifically what the server will do with the message so it would depend on how the server was implemented. By spec, the server, "can then either send the message to a different client, discard it, or put it in a dead letter queue." Which one of these options is chosen will depend on the server. I'm sure there are some servers which support all three options via configuration.

Comment: Okay, so based on message id server can figure out what kinda message type it is and based on that decide what action to take. Got it.

Comment: I didn't say that. I said the behavior depends on how the server was implemented. The STOMP specification is flexible in how it expects a server to handle a NACK. Also, I'm not clear on what you mean by "message type" are you talking about the `content-type` of the STOMP message?

Comment: by message type i mean the type of information that server wants to broadcast to its subscribers. That would be either AUTH_SUCCESS, NEW_CHAT_ENTRY, NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST, UPDATE_ONLINE_STATUS or something of that sort - something that client needs to process. And while for first 3 the server would resend the message if the message was NACKed, for last one server can ignore a NACK because a delivery of online status is not as critical as for first 3 types of messages.

Comment: The server won't know application specific information like that. It only knows about the specifications it supports. Perhaps you can find a server which supports plugins which you might be able to use to implement the behavior you want.

Comment: If you think this answer is correct please mark it as such to help others who users who might have the same question in the future. Thanks!

Comment: yeah i think it makes sense now, i was thinking of STOMP as an application level protocol to implement in your app for client-server communication, but, i mean, it's still application level protocol, but it can be proxied through by a message broker. i understand better now that it's sort of a spec to follow so that it's easier to connect your app to a message broker, if you ever need one. Overkill for my use case, but nevertheless good to know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For what it's worth, a message broker like ActiveMQ Artemis can be embedded in your application so you could exchange messages without needing an external, standalone broker.